# When does Direct Source-Drain tunneling become a problem?

Tags: transistors, cmos, semiconductors, scaling

Because of the probabilistic nature of quantum mechanics, direct source-drain tunneling is bound to happen as a result of CMOS scaling. The smaller the transistors become, the more tunneling occurs.

My question is: Assuming that CMOS scaling continues, when does the tunneling become a serious problem? At what size (minimum feature size/gate length etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

at Lg ~< 10 nm

Still some solutions exist like: 
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=6523122

Comment: They can reduce the probability of tunneling by messing with the effective mass of the charge carriers - Neat. If we could have muon carrier semiconductors CMOS would work to picometers

Comment: Hundreds of picometres anyway, below that at we have no suitable atoms to make our FETs from

Answer (score 0):

Another trick/workaround are finFETs, by moving from a planar device to a "3d" structure leakage in "off" state is reduced while maintaining small device size (in the planar direction anyway), see: http://www.newelectronics.co.uk/electronics-technology/what-makes-finfets-so-compelling/56795/